# Building privately-hosted base image [drone.io]

Tags: docker, drone.io

I am trying to deploy a web service using Drone and the docker plugin. My image takes about an hour to build, due to a number of large dependencies. 
To speed up build times, I would like to place a number of my service's dependencies (that are not going to change often) in a base image, and just build my actual code (a python flask app) on top of this base when deploying.

I am hosting the base image in a private repository, with the following line in my Dockerfile:

`FROM: my_private_repo.com/my_base_image:latest`

but I'm not sure how to correctly give Drone access to this repo.

I currently have the following error in my build job:

`Step 1/11 : FROM:xxx
pull access denied for xxx, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
time="2018-01-17T13:13:33Z" level=fatal msg="exit status 1"`

Is there a way for me to configure the docker plugin to login automatically.
For context, my YAML is something like:

`push-feature:
    image: plugins/docker
    secrets: [docker_username, docker_password]
    repo: xxx/yyy/zzz
    registry: xxx
    tags: "feature"
    when:
      event: push
      branch:
        exclude: [ dev, master ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Do a `docker login` on the host (if you have multiple agents on multiple server you need to do in all agent host servers)
2. Use the `docker` image this repo needs the trusted flag turned on in order to mount host volumes

```yaml
pipeline:
  build:
    image: docker
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock your-private-registry.com:8080
    commands:
      - docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
      - docker build -t myorg/myimage .
```