# drone.io use private repo for pulling FROM image

Tags: docker, drone.io

Have to use a private Image from aws or gcp for my build process in drone.

The simplest DOCKERFILE example:

`FROM ***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/***:latest`

That means i have to login, which works fine. My drone.yml example:

```
steps:
  - name: docker
    privileged: true
    image: revenuehack/drone-ecr-auth
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:
        from_secret: aws_access_id
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:
        from_secret: aws_key
      AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
    commands:
      - aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_REGION --no-include-email | sh
```

But now i have to pull the image and use it in different steps of the ci process. Other questions suggest binding the docker.sock [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326673/building-privately-hosted-base-image-drone-io). Does not feel right to me. Id rather have some sort of service for that. Is that possible? Also this binding does not work:

```
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to build and push an image to your private registry, and then use the private image in next step?

Comment: yes exactly. my workaround at the moment is:
1. to push it to ecr through plugins/ecr
2. pull it with image: ***.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test

i would like to do it without pushing it in the middle

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Global Registry**

Personally I would suggest using the `drone-registry-plugin`, works great to keep access to the ECR repos live:

- https://github.com/drone/drone-registry-plugin

Now, a caveat to this suggestion, is that it mimics the v0.8 global registries function, so all pipelines maintained in the installation would have ability to access the registry.

**Option 2: Local docker `config.json`**

Since this could technically be run by anyone also, I'm not sure what you gain over the registry plugin, but here is the ref:

- https://discourse.drone.io/t/how-to-pull-private-images-with-1-0/3155

This option involves placing a .docker/config.json onto the agents using cloud-init or some other mechanism and then in the individual pipelines you would then be able to add another root level yaml block `image_pull_secrets:`

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: someStep
  image: some.registry.dev/some-image:latest

image_pull_secrets:
- dockerconfigjson
```